# "Integration by parts" formula for functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

We know that for a Hilbert triple $V \subset H \subset V^{'}$, if we have  $u, v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ with $u',v' \in L^2(0,T;V')$
then
$$\frac{d}{dt}(u(t), v(t))_H = u'(t)(v(t)) + v'(t)(u(t))$$
where the $'$ means the weak derivative.

Is there a formula involving weak derivatives for
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)(u(t))$$
where $f(t) \in V^*$ and $u(t) \in V$?

Comment: $u'(t)\in V^*$ and $v(t)\in H$. How do you define $v'(t)(\; v(t)\;)$?

Comment: @Liviu Apologies, $v(t) \in V$. I edited.

Comment: Why doesn't the usual product formula work?

Comment: @Deane by $f(t)(u(t))$ I mean $\langle f(t), u(t) \rangle_{V^*, V}$, the pairing.

Comment: Yes, I know. So why isn't $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle f(t),u(t)\rangle = \langle f'(t),u(t)\rangle + \langle f(t),u'(t)\rangle$$

Comment: @Deane Thanks for response. I did not consider weak derivatives of $f(t)$. But I don't know why $f'(t)$ would exist or why the formula you state is true (or false for that matter). Is it a standard result?

Comment: Why can't you use essentially the same definitions and proof used for the Hilbert space result?