# Generalizing Integration by parts for general bounded continous measure

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, integration

Consider a probability measure $d\mu = w(t) dt$ with $w(t)\in L^1(I)$, $I =\left[ 0,1\right]$. What are the minimal assumption I can take on two functions $f,g:I\ \to \mathbb{R}$ so that an integration by parts -like statement could be made, and what would it be?

Also, can the demands on measure space $\left(\Omega, \mu\right)$ be relaxed so that this result would be still valid? Something with non compact $\Omega$, infinite measure etc.

[This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119407/integration-by-parts-formula-for-functionals) asks a somehow related question, but not quite the same question.

Thanks

Amir

Comment: Perhaps you want the integration by parts for the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%2DStieltjes%5Fintegration#Integration%5Fby%5Fparts

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Isn't there something for functions without bounded variation?